Is the IBMQ cloud simulator no longer available?
Thanks for looking.
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/migration-guides/local-simulators
I have found from this site that cloud simulators cannot be used when doing calculations that deal with large qubits.
There is a limit to the number of bits that can be used in the local environment.
If I want to handle more than 30 qubits, should I use Clifford Simulation?
Does the number of qubits available depend on the specifications of the classical calculator even if Clifford Simulation is used?
I have just studied quantum information.I look forward to your response.

That is correct. The IBMQ cloud simulator is no longer available.
As the article at the link you mentioned explains, IBM is no longer offering simulators in the cloud and recommends running simulations locally instead. The article also includes a list of available simulators and explains which simulators should be used for different purposes.
Disclaimer: I am a quantum hobbyist so take the rest of this answer with a grain of salt.
If you want to simulate more than 30 qubits, you are going to find that to be problematic. While some circuits can be simulated out to hundreds of qubits, those circuits typically are not highly entangled, and most of the bang for the buck you get with quantum computing comes from entanglement.
In general, the efficacy of simulators depends on several factors including not only the number of qubits, but also circuit depth, gate types used (e.g., Clifford vs. non-Clifford gates), number of entanglements, noise model, number of shots, and of course the hardware that you are running the simulator on.
If you want to boost your simulation performance, you could try optimizing or splitting up your circuit, fine tuning your simulation parameters, trying a different simulator, or beefing up your classical hardware. For example, the Aer simulator supports GPU acceleration (https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-aer-gpu/) as well as multi-GPU and multi-node support (https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/howtos/running_gpu.html).
In the end, simulators are good for introductory learning and for developing and testing smaller circuits or parts of larger circuits, so think about what it is that you are really trying to accomplish by simulating 30 qubits, keeping in mind that even supercomputers hit a wall at around 50 qubits for general quantum computing (noting that only a subset of circuit types can be simulated more efficiently).
And finally, remember that if a large number of qubits and quantum gates could be efficiently simulated on classical computers, then real quantum computers wouldn't really be valuable or necessary, so don't be surprised at the limitations of simulators.
